# Manage content and structure copy page is not setting same content type on target page list item

Tags: 2007, content-type, out-of-the-box, copy-and-paste

In SharePoint you have the ability to copy pages from one list to another. I have a page in list 1 which is set to use the **Page** content type. When I copy this same page to list 2 (same web) it copies the page but assigns the content type to the article content type, when it should have been page content type. This causes the users confusion because now it won't let them set the page to use the available publishing layouts.

My question how do you get SharePoint to assign the same content type to the page that the user has copied over, or ensure that the default content type for a given list is **Page** and not **Article**?